# How to call a method that takes multiple parameters in c#

Tags: c#, methods

i am new at c# and i have a problem in this small program
i want to return the entered information in method ClientsDetails to use them in method Print(). 
Any help plz ?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ClientsDetails();

        Print(???,???,???);

        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    public static void ClientsDetails()
    {
        Console.Write("Client's first name: ");
        string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Client's last name: ");
        string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Client's birthdate: ");
        string birthday = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Print(string first, string last, string birthday)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client : {0} {1} was born on: {2}", first, last, Birthday);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may study more about the C# first, it look like a homework rather than a particular question.

Comment: Looks like you read the class materials as well as you did [Ask] or the [faq]

Comment: Hello @Alex, i am already in course wtih Bob Tabor. thanks for your reply

Comment: Do you have to use the Print method in your Main method?

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, and they are preventing you from using global variables, you should provide a link to the assignment... Also, you can return an array from strings from your ClientDetails section

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a heap of way that you can pass the required arguments to your method, so for example simply you can do it like this:

```
String f = "first string";
String l = "last string";
String b = "birthday string";
Print(f,l,b);
```

BTW, in your case it seems that you want the user's inputs to be passed to the `Print` method, so a simple way is to just call the `Print` method inside your `ClientsDetails` method like this:

```
Print(firstName, lastName, birthday);
```

For a comprehensive resource about this, you can refer to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx), as always. At the moment you can just neglect the `Async Methods` part.

Comment: hello @mok, the arguments are entered by the user in method ClientsDetails(), i need the same arguments to be used in method Print(),

Comment: @Khalil {Hi}. The other way is to return the values of variables which are filled by users outside the `ClientsDetails` method, e.g. by passing `out` parameters to the method.

Comment: Dear @mok, calling Print() in ClientsDetails() method solved the problem, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a struct:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    struct Person{
        public static FirstName;
        public static LastName;
        public static Birthday;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                
            Person person = ClientsDetails();
            Print(person.FirstName, person.LastName, person.Birthday);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static Person ClientsDetails()
        {
            Person returnValue = new Person();
            Console.Write("Client's first name: ");
            returnValue.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Client's last name: ");
            returnValue.LastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Client's birthdate: ");
            returnValue.Birthday = Console.ReadLine();
            return returnValue;
        }

        public static void Print(string first, string last, string birthday)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Client : {0} {1} was born on: {2}", first, last, birthday));
        }
    }
}
```

Or an array:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                
            string person = ClientsDetails();
            Print(person[0], person[1], person[2]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static string[] ClientsDetails()
        {
            string[] returnValue = new string[3];
            Console.Write("Client's first name: ");
            returnValue[0] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Client's last name: ");
            returnValue[1] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Client's birthdate: ");
            returnValue[3] = Console.ReadLine();
            return returnValue;
        }

        public static void Print(string first, string last, string birthday)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Client : {0} {1} was born on: {2}", first, last, birthday));
        }
    }
}
```

Or references (pass by reference):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {       
            string firstName, lastName, birthday;
            ClientsDetails(ref firstName, ref lastName, ref birthday);
            Print(firstName, lastName, birthday);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void ClientsDetails(ref string firstName, ref string lastName, ref string birthday)
        {
            Console.Write("Client's first name: ");
            firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Client's last name: ");
            lastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Client's birthdate: ");
            birthday = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Print(string first, string last, string birthday)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Client : {0} {1} was born on: {2}", first, last, birthday));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @Jered, Thank you so much for your very useful answer.
it will help me to understand "struct" and "pass by reference"

Answer (score 0):

I just corrected your program as your requirement.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static String FirstName;
        private static String LastName;
        private static String Birthday;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClientsDetails();
            Print(FirstName, LastName, Birthday);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void ClientsDetails()
        {
            Console.Write("Client's first name: ");
            FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Client's last name: ");
            LastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Client's birthdate: ");
            Birthday = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Print(string first, string last, string birthday)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Client : {0} {1} was born on: {2}", first, last, Birthday));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Touhid, declaring the three arguments outside the methods isn't a choice, i would do it if it was permitted, but no i need them to be declared in the method ClientsDetails() then use them in the main method when calling the method Print(), Thank you for your kindly reply

Comment: You can not access the variables from another method directly. So I declare 3 variable to the class and assigned from theClientsDetails() . so the assigned variables can be accessed from anywhere.

Comment: I've upvoted this becuase I don't think it should have been down voted. You didn't mention that requirement in the description so this is a valid answer. Knowing that requirement now I've also given a reply.